# I need to create unit tests for my urls in a django project

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I have this url which returns the json data of my models but I don't know how to create a unit test for a url like this

```
path("list/", views.json_list, name="json_list"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what is being asked. A test like this

```
url = reverse('myapp:json_list')
response = client.get( url)
body = response.content.decode()
```

is going to fail if anything is wrong with the url definition. (Specifically, `reverse` will fail if the name doesn't exist, and for an url with arguments, if what you supply as `kwargs` isn't accepted by the url definition).

As for validating the response, we can't help without knowing a lot more about what is expected. Presumably, you will locate the start of some JSON text in `body`, feed it to `json.loads`, and make sure the data is as expected. But I don't think that's what is being asked.

Comment: But what do I do with this "body" variable?

Comment: @Ivan_Campelo it contains the html text that your browser displays when you visit the URL. You can not bother to decode it, or do a quick sanity check that it contains some particular substring, or parse it in excruciating detail ... it all depends on what you are testing

Comment: this url refers to a view that takes the data from a given model and returns everything in json. I wanted to test if everything is ok, if it will return json to me

Comment: @ivan_campelo I'd start by using `print( body[:2000])` to see what the JSON is wrapped up with and how to identify where it starts ... then replace print with suitable test code. `json.loads` will probably be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I'm working on this project and I need to do unit tests for everything. I'm quite confused. Do you have any tips or information from the web that could give me an upgrade on this issue?

Comment: @ivan_campelo If you are working in a team, you need to seek guidance as to what is expected of your unit tests. Otherwise ask another question, with the code of `views.json_list`, asking for advice on how to test it.